# Inserting values to two tables

Tags: java, sql

I have two tables `table1` and `table2` when I inserting first insert become successfull and while at second got an exception. Then I want to remove the first table's value. How it can
done in JAVA and SQL.

Thanks in advance;

Comment: What exception? Please show your code! More details please!

Comment: What DB? Are you performing the inserting via java code?

Answer (score 2):

This is handled by the fact that the database is transactional. Disable autocommit on your JDBC connection, commit after the two statements are successfully executed, or rollback if any of them has failed, and the database will rollback (cancel) the insertion of both statements.

Read the [JDBC tutorial about transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to put the two insert statements inside a [Database transaction](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions), so that either the two statements completed successfully or rollback if one of them failed, depending on database engine you are using, for mysql see [this](http://%20%5BTransaction%5D%5B2%5D), it might be something  like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    Insert into table1 values("....") ;
    Insert into table2 values("....");
COMMIT;
```

For SQL Server see [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

While you don't commit your change, you always can do a rollback to cancel your transaction. So if you send your query with JAVA (I don't know your code) and that you get an Exception then you can send a rollback to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using disable auto commit. Then perform your insert value's, if the second one fails execute a rollback. If you want more specific help you will have to provide additional information.